# Count dynamic items and then split

Tags: c#, split

I have a dynamic string Eg:

```
string HtS ="10 11 1 2       '...many spaces...'       ";
```

The spaces are because the string is from nchar(80) from sqlserver type.I want to count the items that will splitted and then split them.

```
int cP = Regex.Matches(HtS, " ").Count;
string[] HSlist = HtS.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, cP);
```

the problem is that the string is splitted and the count is 72 items.4 items 10 11 1 2 and 68 empty items
The right result must be 4. I need this count of items for future use in a for...

any suggestion?

Comment: Shouldn't the correct count be 3 ?

Comment: This is needlessly complicated - just call Split without passing the number of items, and it will know what to do.

Comment: @ChrisLaplante I think he needs to use the count in a loop later down the road (as far as I understood).

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov If that's the case then he can just use the size of the array returned.

Comment: @ChrisLaplante But, unless I misunderstood he needs the count of the spaces, not the elements themselves ? Maybe he can shed some light ? Yeah, dude ?

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov; Yes, he is counting spaces; I have no idea why. However, the second line appears to try to extract the elements.

Comment: I want to count elements for a later loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, unless I'm missing something, here it is:

```
string HtS = "10 11 1 2       ".Trim(); // removes the spaces at the end
int count = HtS.Count(x => x.Equals(' ')); // = 3 -> counting the spaces
string[] HSlist = HtS.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int elementsCount = HSlist.Length; // = 4
```

Comment: the string is "10 11 1 2        ...70spaces....        " because is from nchar(80) sqlserver type. With you code gives me again 72

Answer (score 2):

Trim the spaces from the original string and then split

```
 string HtS = "10 11 1 2                         ..lots of spaces.......";
 HtS = HtS.Trim();

 string[] HSlist = HtS.Split(' ');
```

This will provide you with expeected output

> `HSlist.Length` is 4
>
> `HSlist[0]`  is 10
>
> `HSlist[1]`  is 11
>
> `HSlist[2]`  is 1
>
> `HSlist[3]`  is 2

I hope this is what you actually wanted to achieve.

Comment: yes.Exactly what I want.I use trimEnd().I think is the same.many thanks